# Adding new tab to WordPress editor next to visual and text tab

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce-4

Hi as I already said in topic title, I want to add another tab next to visual and text tab.

So far I found this topic here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994660/add-new-tab-next-to-visual-and-html-in-wordpress-text-editor

But it doesn't help me much.

Is there any other way to add another tab to default WordPress editor, instead of creating new one?

Regards